# Meross 3-Way Switch installation where the first box connects the power source, light, and second switch cables

Tags: electrical, wiring, home-automation

[image]

I'm looking to add a Meross MSS550 3-way switch.  My wiring matches this diagram.  The Meross switch requires a Live, Neutral, Ground, and 2 traveler wires.  It only requires the replacement of one switch, and I'm looking to replace the left switch in the diagram.

My question is if it's OK to rewire it such that the live Black wire from the source connects into the common terminal switch on the left?  Subsequently can the Black wire from the Right switch connect with the Black wire leading to the light.

Based on that answer, I'll have the 5 wires identified to swapping out the left switch with my new  Meross unit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand how that works.  **However**.

When neutral is not in a cable, and always-hot *is* in a cable, **white must be always-hot**.  (and it must still have marking tape indicating that it is a hot).

So you may reverse the 3-way configuration to take always-hot to the far switch.  But this means you must change (on both switches) which ones are the traveler wires.   White must become always-hot, and black/red become the travelers.

Comment: I think that's how it is now.  The diagram above is what I observed without changing anything.  Currently black is hot.  It's connected to the black wire over to the other switch.  The other switch has no neutral.  Black goes out to it, Red and White are the travelers that come back.  (I'll give the original electrician the benefit of the doubt and assume the black mark on the white wire wore off :) )

Comment: That's  a much more reasonable assumption.  I always gave the benefit of the doubt that the tape was there, but I was just momentarily black-white colorblind :)